# What distribution does this pdf belong to?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta -1}$, $0<x<1$, $\theta > 0$

To me, it almost looks like a Pareto distribution but not quite. I see it popping up a lot but could not find an exact name for it in my searches. Does it belong to a distribution that has a name?

Edit: from playing around with the pdf, $\log(X)$ seems to be an exponential distribution.

Comment: The [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) has pdf $$\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}} {B(\alpha,\beta)}$$ and support $(0,1)$, so set $\beta = 1$ and we have it.

Comment: @JairTaylor that does not have the parameter $\alpha$ as a factor out front though right?

Comment: It does.  You don't even need to check constant factors because in the formula because they are determined by $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 1$. But I'll add an answer confirming this.

Comment: @JairTaylor I see it now. It comes from the denominator of your comment. Thank you

Comment: When $\beta=1$ in the Beta distribution, it is sometimes called a "standard power function distribution".  It is $-\log(X)$ which is an exponential distribution, with rate $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) which has pdf $$\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}} {B(\alpha,\beta)}$$ and support $(0,1)$ where $$B(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}.$$  We set $\alpha = \theta$ and $\beta = 1$. At this point we are done, because any two pdfs $f(x), cf(x)$ on the same domain $D$ that are the same up to a constant factor must be the same, since if both are true pdfs they must have integral equal to one and so  $1 = \int_D cf(x) \, dx = c\int_D f(x) \, dx = c\cdot1 = c$.

But just to check, we use two facts about the Gamma function, namely, $\Gamma(x+1) = x \Gamma(x)$ and $\Gamma(1) = 1$. We have

$$B(\theta, 1) = \frac{\Gamma(\theta) \Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(\theta + 1)} = \frac{\Gamma(\theta)}{\theta \Gamma(\theta)} = 1/\theta.$$